# How to download multiple files at once?

Tags: windows, download, file-download

I'm trying to download multiple files from different URL's. These files are in zip format. So for example : h`ttp://site/filedir1` returns a List of zip files that can be downloaded at that URL. There is no ftp server running at this address so they must be access over http. Is there a tool to download these files at specified URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do it in the browser rather than that Extreme Picture thing, I wrote a Chrome extension which you can just paste URLs into and have them download, or if you need slightly different behaviour the code's all [here](https://github.com/lmmx/tabsave) on GitHub.

It'll work across all platforms (operating systems) i.e. Windows/Mac/Linux, download link is [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify how are you trying to download.To get anything through **ftp**( usually port 21 ) you must have the password, if you are downloading by Web Browser you can only get it through https or http (usually port 80 ).For Windows And Linux there r many programs which can download many files from many servers  simultaneously. (IDM , WeGet).